# Как сделать NSArray или NSDictionary из json

Tags: ios, ios7

Ребят, объясните как сделать `NSArray` или `NSDictionary` из `json`:

```
"myNumber": "433",
    "rating": {
        "hours": "31",
        "marksCount": "4",
        "mark": "18",
        "absence": "2"
    },
    "dataFilled": true,
    "header": {
        "content": ""
    }
```

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример тут: [JsonToDictionary](https://github.com/oscarvgg/JsonToDictionary)

Comment: спасибо огромное что откликнулись но мне бы хотелось разобраться именно с этими данными я не могу понят как их в массив и в словарь положить

Comment: наверное как-то так:

NSString *MyJsonString = @"myNumber": "433", "rating": { "hours": "31", "marksCount": "4", "mark": "18", "absence": "2" }, "dataFilled": true, "header": { "content": "" }"

[JsonToDictionary diccionaryFromJsonString:MyJsonString];

будет вам "NSArray или NSDictionary из json".

Comment: спасибо огромное